# Reading Neonomicon before The Courtyard

Tags: comics, suggested-order, neonomicon, the-courtyard

Could one read Alan Moore's four-issue series *Neonomicon* before reading the two-issue series *The Courtyard*?

If the plot is already set in *The Courtyard*, is the reader going to understand anything in the *Neonomicon*?

Comment: Before or after, I heavily recommend you re-read them while following the [online annotations](https://factsprovidence.wordpress.com/moore-lovecraft-comics-annotation-index/), because there's a lot of hidden depth to these comics that's easy to miss. And do *not* miss *Providence*, which in my opinion is by far the best of them all (but one *needs* the annotations to get a full grasp on everything that's going on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The narrative of Neonomicon is independent of the Courtyard, and makes sense without it. However, you will miss important character details. You'll be able to glean what you need from context, but there's really no reason to not just read The Courtyard first and get the full experience.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. Thanks for your help!